# Search custom post on basis of post_content, metaboxes and taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
// Start the Query

    $v_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'listing',
        'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                    'key'     => 'wpcf-services',
                    'value'   => $services,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                    ),
        'tax_query' =>array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-city',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $location,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'listing-category',
                        'field' => 'name',
                        'terms' => $listing_category,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'operator' => 'IN'
                ),
                ),

    );

     $listingsearch = new WP_Query( $v_args );?>
```

this search working fine for custom post type but i want to search on post_content also how i achieve this.

This search work on custom meta and taxonomy but not on post_content

My requirement is when enter value in $services textbox it compare the value from post_content and metabox (wpcf-services) both with OR logic

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code for, if it would help you,

```
$v_args = array(
    'post_type'     =>  'listing',
    's' => $services_textbox,
    'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                'key'     => 'wpcf-services',
                'value'   => $services,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                ),
    'tax_query' =>array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'listing-city',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $location,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'listing-category',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $listing_category,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'operator' => 'IN'
            ),
            ),

    );

    $listingsearch = new WP_Query( $v_args );
```